# retrieve a text from paragraph and change its color

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

search.lengthIs there a way to retrieve a text from paragraph and change its color?

i tryed:

```
<p id="userInput">1,2,3,4,5,6,7,some text,another text</p>

 var qq = document.getElementById("userInput").innerHTML.match(/5/g); 
 var blaaa = qq.style.color = "red";
 document.getElementById("userInput").innerHTML = blaaa;
```

EDIT:

```
var search = ['new', 'and'];
$(document).ready(function () {
    for(var i = 0;i<2;i++){
    $("div:contains('"+search[i]+"')").each(function () {
        var regex = new RegExp(search[i],'gi');
        $(this).html($(this).text().replace(regex, "<span class='red'>"+search[i]+"</span>"));
    });
    }
});
```

Comment: do you want to change color of paragraph tag content or replace text with other content?

Comment: try this $("#userInput").css('color','red');

Comment: @PawanLakhara i just need to search for text in paragraph and change its color to red (not whole p to red, just some part of it.Example: <p = "userInput">aa , bb, cc, dd</p> and var q = "cc" .In p, change only cc color to red if var q ="cc" in this case

Comment: check this link http://jsfiddle.net/PELkt/

Comment: @PawanLakhara nice one man! i'll try to adapt for my situation. THX alot!

Comment: @PawanLakhara i have added and EDIT using your code... am i wrong somewhere?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No there isn't, unless you wrap the text in it's own element, for instance a span

```js
var el = document.getElementById("userInput");

el.innerHTML = el.innerHTML.replace(/(5)/g, '<span style="color: red">$1</span>');
```

```html
<p id="userInput">1,2,3,4,5,6,7,some text,another text</p>
```

Comment: Could i change color for multiple texts in p? i've got an array = ["5" , "7"] and i need to change in <p id="userInput">3 , 5 , 6, 7, 8</p> color of 5 and 7 only? Keep in mind that array can change its values (5 and 7 are examples) and <p> text too

Comment: If you want to change both 5 and 7, you can change the regex to `/(5|7)/g` etc. -> http://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/L05xu2nz/